# Converting ASCII string into binary to add Parity

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert ASCII strings into Binary so i can add Parity to it (Hamming Code). But the output is not right at all.

If i enter 'A' on the input it should return:
01000001
and i've tried it with 'B' but it doesn't return that

```
unsigned char bits[8];
for(int i = 8; i >= 1; i--){
```

i expect the output to be 01000001 for 'A' 
but the actual output is 00100000
Same for ABC or B or C

Comment: upper bit is 7, lower bit is 0. you're shifting too much with your for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` is off by one, so you are accessing elements `bitC[8]` to `bitC[1]` (even though `bitC[8]` is out of bounds), and you are printing bits 8 to 1 instead of bits 7 to 0.

Replace

```
for(int i = 8; i >= 1; i--){
```

with

```
for(int i = 8; i--; ){
```

Comment: `for(int i = 8; i--; ){` is bad and hacking style. Please use `for (int i = 7; i >=0; i--) {`! Or if you have a constant for your magic number, `for (int i = BITS_PER_BYTE - 1; i >= 0; i--) {`.

Comment: @the busybee, Magic numbers are bad, sure (but I'm not sure using a constant adds clarity here). The other change is outright bad. though. It's equivalent but more complicated code. Ease of reading is key is good software, so an easily-readable and easily-recognizable common idiom trumps longer and harder to recognize code every day, even if newcomers must spend two seconds learning it.

Comment: C's for loop is incredibly hard to read to begin with. For example, it's super hard to see the differences between `for (int i = BITS_PER_BYTE - 1; i >= 0; i--)`, `for (int i = BITS_PER_BYTE; i >= 0; i--)`, `for (int i = BITS_PER_BYTE - 1; i > 0; i--)`, and `for (int i = BITS_PER_BYTE - 1; i >= 0; i--)` at a glance. Keeping it to a minimum is key. (Maximizing its use by using multiple variables or in some other way that can't possibly be confused for an idiom would also be ok. You'd lose the advantage of quick recognition, but it won't be mistaken for the wrong thing.)

Comment: Relying on zero being false is good thing. And relying on the value returned by postdecrement isn't bad -- there's literally no other reason for its existence! (I'd instantly wonder if you made a mistake when I look at your code that uselessly uses postdecrement. Bad! Don't make the reader wonder such things.)

Comment: The reason for pre- and postdecrement returning a value was in the dark ages of K&R-C when processor power was really low and the compilers primitive. Working on safety-related projects in C for decades gives me enough reasons to reject such hackish style.

Comment: Using `i--` for two separated things (decrement [and relying on the knowledge what value is has] and checking for zero) is asking for desaster. Additionally it misleads beginners to think that `if (!ptr)` is good style, which it is **not**. Source code has to be clear and upfront understandable for the swift and/or casual reader. And you are right, "don't make the reader wonder": Don't make her wonder what `i--` has to do at a place where a boolean should be.

Comment: @the busybee, `if (!ptr)` **is** good style. Needless extra clutter just reduces readability.

Comment: Re "*Don't make her wonder what i-- has to do at a place where a boolean should be.*", Your point makes no sense. `i--` returns a boolean. Besides, that whole idea about idoms is that you don't have to wonder. It's instantly obvious because you've seen it a million times before.

Comment: I found it interesting that you didn't mention that two of the four snippets I posted were identical. Again, long complicated for loops are very hard to read, and that's the very definition of bad programming.

Comment: `i--` returns the type of `i`, not a boolean. It's a design error of C that scalar types are silently cast to boolean. And it's a design error that the (controlling) expressions for `if` and loops is a scalar type. Both are from dark histories kept for compatibilty, I'm afraid. But let's stop this discussion as none of us will give up.

Comment: @the busybee, `i--` returning an `int` doesn't preclude from also being a boolean value (a value that either true or false). This is not a "dark past" thing. It is found in both old (C, Perl) and new (JavaScript, Python) languages.